# How to remove multiple return from method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, error-handling, return, refactoring

I have a class `A` to handle errors,
How can I refactor it to remove multiple returns from call method.

Basically when `if true` then return from the method with `error` and `success` false.

```
Class A

  def call
    return method1  if true/false
    return method2  if true/false
    return method3  if true/false
    { success: true }
  end

  private

  def method1
  {
    success: false 
    errors: 'X Not Found.'
  }
  end

  def method2
  {
    success: false 
    errors: 'Y Not Found.'
  }
  end


  def method3
  {
    success: false 
    errors: 'Z Not Found.'
  }
  end
end
```

Comment: You could use a [`case` expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) instead, or depending on your conditions, some `if-elsif`'s

Comment: How do you determine `true/false` in your example? What is the condition?

Comment: Based on model level conditions. It has set of methods from model which return true or false.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to remove the multiple returns because someone told you that clean code should only have one return? If so, you are mistaken: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from

Comment: Yes. I will show him this. Thanks.

Comment: Please only use valid Ruby code for your example. That is in part so that readers can show how your code could be modified in answers and comments. `if true/false` and the definitions of `methodx` obviously will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since `true` is always `true`, the first conditional will always be `true` and thus the first `return` will always be executed. Therefore, everything after the first `return` is simply dead code and will never be reached. You can simplify the `call` method to this, which is 100% equivalent to your code:

```rb
def call
  method1
end
```

Or, alternatively

```rb
alias_method :call, :method1
```

Since `method2` and `method3` are no longer called from anywhere, you can just remove them.

Since `method1` is only called from one place, namely `call`, you can just inline it, and so your entire class becomes this:

```rb
class A
  def call
    {
      success: false 
      errors: 'X Not Found.'
    }
  end
end
```

This is 100% equivalent to your code and does exactly the same thing in all situations. (Modulo violating encapsulation via unrestricted reflection.)

Comment: It can be false as well. Edited the question.

Comment: It is considered rude to edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Please, consider reverting the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could add code of the conditionals too otherwise it's quite hard to come up with a solution. Anyway, you could have a `success?` and `message` method and just format it in the class method.

```rb
Class A
  def call
    {
      success: success?
      errors: message
    }.compact
  end

  private

  def success?
    if x || y || z
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end

  def message
    if x
      'Y Not Found.'
    elsif y
      'Y Not Found.'
    elsif z
      'Z Not Found.'
    end
  end
end
```

Please note the `compact` in the calls method which will remove the message key if it's empty (in case of success).